# jquery: when hide a field is value still available

Tags: jquery

Hi I am hiding a field in one of my apps using jquery('').hide();  I want to know, if you use the hide function, is the value within the hidden field still accessible?  My code grabs the value out of this hidden field then sends an email - so I want to be sure the email address is actually there

Comment: Yes the value hidden field and value will be here and you can access it

Comment: wouldn't it be quicker to test it than asking here ?

Comment: [Why not just try it ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the value is still available.

```
var value = $('#hideme').hide().val();
```

... will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Per jQuery's documentation at http://api.jquery.com/hide/

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none')...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The visual display of an element has nothing to do with the element's value in the DOM. The entire category of `<input type="hidden">` would not work if this were not true.

A quick test can prove this:

```
$('#foo').hide();
console.log($('#foo').val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JbDCB/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function merely removes the element from the rendering of the page. The markup itself is still there (which is why you can use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to show it again), so you can get the value whenever you want, and it will be unaltered.

Answer (score -1):

Hiding doesn't clear it no. Use `jQuery('#id').html('');` to clear it from content.

Comment: He want to know whther the value gets cleared. and not to clear the value @CaptainCarl

Comment: Read the first sentence of my post than :)